# Object Specific ArrayList C++ Issue

Tags: c++

I currently have a Person class, and have created a PersonList class that extends List, specifically for objects of type Person. When I instantiate a new PersonList I get one error that stops the entire build from happening successfully:

error C2678: binary '==' : no operator found which takes a left-hand operand of type 'Person' (or there is no acceptable conversion)    c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include\xutility   3186    1   ConsoleApplication3

Here is the PersonList class:

```
#pragma once
#include<iostream>
#include<sstream>
#include<string>
#include<algorithm>
#include "linearList.h"
#include "myExceptions.h"
#include "changeLength1D.h"
#include <Person.h>

using namespace std;

template<class Person>
class PersonList: public linearList<Person> 
{
public:
PersonList(int initialCapacity = 10);
PersonList(const PersonList<Person>&);
~PersonList() {delete [] element;}

bool empty() const {return listSize == 0;}
  int size() const {return listSize;}
  Person& get(int theIndex) const;
  int indexOf(const Person& theElement) const;
  void erase(int theIndex);
  void insert(int theIndex, const Person& theElement);
  void output(ostream& out) const;

  // additional method
  int capacity() const {return arrayLength;}

  protected:
  void checkIndex(int theIndex) const;
        // throw illegalIndex if theIndex invalid
  Person* element;            // 1D array to hold list elements
  int arrayLength;       // capacity of the 1D array
  int listSize;          // number of elements in list
  };

template<class Person>
PersonList<Person>::PersonList(int initialCapacity)
{// Constructor.
if (initialCapacity < 1)
{ostringstream s;
  s << "Initial capacity = " << initialCapacity << " Must be > 0";
 throw illegalParameterValue(s.str());
}
arrayLength = initialCapacity;
element = new Person[arrayLength];
listSize = 0;
 }

template<class Person>
PersonList<Person>::PersonList(const PersonList<Person>& theList)
{// Copy constructor.
arrayLength = theList.arrayLength;
listSize = theList.listSize;
element = new Person[arrayLength];
copy(theList.element, theList.element + listSize, element);
}


template<class Person>
void PersonList<Person>::checkIndex(int theIndex) const
{// Verify that theIndex is between 0 and listSize - 1.
if (theIndex < 0 || theIndex >= listSize)
{ostringstream s;
s << "index = " << theIndex << " size = " << listSize;
throw illegalIndex(s.str());
}

}

template<class Person>
Person& PersonList<Person>::get(int theIndex) const
{// Return element whose index is theIndex.
 // Throw illegalIndex exception if no such element.
 checkIndex(theIndex);
 return element[theIndex];
 }   

 template<class Person>
int PersonList<Person>::indexOf(const Person& theElement) const
{// Return index of first occurrence of theElement.
 //  Return -1 if theElement not in list.

  // search for theElement
  int theIndex = (int) (find(element, element + listSize, theElement)
                     - element);

   // check if theElement was found
  if (theIndex == listSize)
   // not found
    return -1;
    else return theIndex;
    }

template<class Person>
void PersonList<Person>::erase(int theIndex)
{// Delete the element whose index is theIndex.
 // Throw illegalIndex exception if no such element.
 checkIndex(theIndex);

 // valid index, shift elements with higher index
 copy(element + theIndex + 1, element + listSize,
                            element + theIndex);

   element[--listSize].~Person(); // invoke destructor
  }



template<class Person>
void PersonList<Person>::insert(int theIndex, const Person& theElement)
{// Insert theElement so that its index is theIndex.
if (theIndex < 0 || theIndex > listSize)
{// invalid index
  ostringstream s;
  s << "index = " << theIndex << " size = " << listSize;
  throw illegalIndex(s.str());
}

// valid index, make sure we have space
 if (listSize == arrayLength)
  {// no space, double capacity
     changeLength1D(element, arrayLength, 2 * arrayLength);
     arrayLength *= 2;
  }

  // shift elements right one position
   copy_backward(element + theIndex, element + listSize,
             element + listSize + 1);

    element[theIndex] = theElement;

     listSize++;
    }

template<class Person>
void PersonList<Person>::output(ostream& out) const
{// Put the list into the stream out.
 copy(element, element + listSize, ostream_iterator<Person>(cout, "  "));
 }

// overload <<
template <class Person>
ostream& operator<<(ostream& out, const PersonList<Person>& x)
 {x.output(out); return out;}
```

The Person Class:

```
#pragma once
#include <string>

using namespace std;


class Person
{
public:
Person(string firstName, string lastName, string birthday, string hometown);
Person(void);
~Person(void);
string name;
string birthday;
string hometown;
};
```

The same thing happens in an arrayList class I tried using earlier. Is there a way to get it so I can simply store person objects in an ArrayList type structure?

Comment: Is `operator==` implemented for the `Person` class?

Comment: No, How exactly do you implement an operator?

Comment: linearList is an abstract class that defines the main methods used in list structures

Comment: @AlexAlex, just compare those members, that needs to be compared.

Comment: but how do I implement "==" for an object that isn't primitive or string type?

Comment: @AlexAlex, show the `Person` class

Comment: @AlexAlex, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421706/operator-overloading

Answer (score 1):

Your function `indexOf()` contains a call to STL's `std::find()` algorithm, which internally performs comparisons between pairs of values to determine if the element passed as a third argument is contained in the range defined by the first two arguments.

To perform this comparison, `std::find()` uses the `==` operator. However, no `operator ==` has been defined for objects of type `Person`.

In order to solve the problem, you must overload the comparison operator `==` for instances of `Person`. You can do it, for instance, this way:

```
class Person
{
    ...
public:
    friend bool operator == (Person const& p1, Person const& p2)
    {
        // Perform the comparison and return "true" if the objects are equal
        return (p1.name == p2.name) && ... 
    }
};
```

Comment: Ok, that seems to work for the "==". It then brings up the "<<" operator with the same message. Do I have to overload all the operators in order to use arrayList?

Comment: @AlexAlex: Yes. That's because you use `std::copy` and `ostream_iterator`, which actually result in output insertions. Output insertions use the `operator <<` so, if you want to output an object of type `Person` you need to overload `operator <<`. I assume you know how to do it, because I see you've done it for the class template `PersonList`.